# Untouchable UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol

I have table view cell with segmented control on it. I want to make my cell untouchable. It shouldn't highlight grey when user touches it. If I set user interaction enabled property to false, segmented control, doesn't work. How should I make my cell untouchable to work with segmented control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undtouchable means, that there is no User Interaction allowed (also with all your Controls inside your Cell)

If you just want to remove the cell selection, set this to None:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: This will disable the colour when touched. If you also want to disable to selection action, return `nil` from `-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for that row.

Answer (score 0):

As @thelaws said, tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: should be used here, generally it is used when you want to select some other row ( row other than selected by the user) but if you return nil, it will not select any row.

And for disabling selection color just use

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];